# How DBMS Process different types of joins?

Tags: sql, database

How a database engines process sql joins? Do they apply different technique to process different type of joins? Explanation with example will be appreciated.

Comment: This might be interesting for your: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join

Answer (score 1):

Query evaluation is very complex. I recommend that you pick up a Database textbook and read the portion on query evaluation of your favourite DMBS's documentation.

In a nutshell, there exist 3 main types of algorithms: single pass, loop based, and sort/merged based. Each is used depending on the number of tuples in the tables to join, the expected number of joined tuples, the size of memory and the disk speed (if properly tuned), the existence of indexes, and how good the planner of the DBMS is.

Single pass happen when the table to be joined fits in memory.
Loop-based is usually done when one table fits completely in memory (they can be index, or hash based).
Multiple passes are required for sort/merge based joins.

This URL has some good examples:

http://etutorials.org/SQL/Postgresql/Part+I+General+PostgreSQL+Use/Chapter+4.+Performance/Understanding+How+PostgreSQL+Executes+a+Query/

--dmg